# Changing the colour of a dodged barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, statistics, bar-chart

I'm currently struggling to change the default colours of a barplot I made. Since I used a value for the `aes(fill="")` argument the addition of `scale_colour_x` or `scale_fill_x` does not work. I'll provide you with the code I have and hope you'll find an easy way to solve my problem with me.

```
set.seed(123)
platelay <- data.frame(rown = rep(letters[1:8], 4),
                       coln = rep(1:4,each = 8),
                       colorvar = rnorm(32, 0.3, 0.2))
```

The example data (supposed to be a part of a 96 microwellplate with different fluorescence readouts per well)

```
ggplot(platelay,aes(x=rown,y=colorvar,fill=coln)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

The plot should give 5 bars (one for each `coln`) per `rown` and I want them to have colours which make it easy to distinguish each bar.

This is what it looks like right now:
[image: dodged barplot]

As you can see the colours blend and the scale shows not only the distinct values 1 to 4 but also halves.
I would appreciate the slightest bit of help, since I'm not really familiar with R or coding at all (just started learning it last week).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that color because your fill variable coln is not factor. Just convert it into factor and you can add required colors manually using scale_fill_manual(). You can either give names of color or you can give the hex codes of the required color.

```
ggplot(platelay,aes(x=rown,y=colorvar, fill = as.factor(coln)))+
geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "#e50000", "#cc0000","green"))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a bit better, but not quite what I'm looking for. I would like to customize the colours for each bar. So e.g. that the left one is blue, the middle ones different shades of red and the right one is green.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Big thanks for that. Although I don't know why it didn't when I tried it in the first place. nvm!